# How can I reverse a 'fn' key on a Dell keyboard so that F1,F2,F3... are used as default?

Tags: keyboard, dell, keyboard-layout

To be more clear, right now the volume and brightness keys are used and I have to hold <kbd>fn</kbd> in order to execute an <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>... command. Can I reverse this so it's function key by default and holding <kbd>fn</kbd> enables the volume and other special controls?

Comment: This is a question related to hardware/firmware, so [off-topic for Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), it would better fit to [su]. (Correct me if I am wrong…)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are 2 methods to change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> behavior.

- **Method 1:**
  Try one of the following combination:
  <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>NumLock</kbd>
  <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> key (it’s the one before a 1 on most US keyboards)
  <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- **Method 2:**
  Change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> behavior from the BIOS menu.
  After you open the BIOS menu, go to *Function Key Behavior*.
  Then select Function Key First (if it doesn't work, repeat and select Multimedia Key First).

Comment: Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: To my knowledge, these are the only ways to reverse the Fn key.

Comment: **Fn** + **ESC** works on me, using Xiaomi MIIIW keyboard! thanks for the solution!!

Comment: @AdityaKresnaPermana, glad it helped you :-)

Comment: Fn + ESC works on Logitech Ergo K860

Comment: On the dell latitude 5110, you need to choose `Fn lock` in the EUFI. Only then can you lock the choice to either the primary or secondary use

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on a DELL using the ESC key, you will see a small padlock with FN written inside it.
Press and hold FN key then tap the escape (padlock) key and then let both go at the same time. FN is then switched, to switch back, same operation.
.